# How to test the rust standard library?

Tags: testing, standard-library, rust-0.11

I'd like to make some changes to my copy of the rust standard library, then run the tests in the source files I changed. I do not need to test the compiler itself. How can I do this without testing a lot of things I am not changing and do not care about?

Here are some things I've already tried. A note - the specific file I want to play around with is `libstd/io/net/pipes.rs` in rust 0.12.0.

1. I tried `rustc --test pipes.rs` - the imports and options are not set up properly, it seems, and a multitude of errors is the result.
2. Following [the rust test suite documentation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/wiki/Note-testsuite), I tried `make check-stage1-std NO_REBUILD=1`, but this failed with "can't find crate for `green`". A person on the #rust-internals irc channel informed me that "make check-stage1 breaks semi-often as it's not the 'official way' to run tests."
3. Another person on that channel suggested `make check-stage0-std`, which seems to check libstd, but doesn't restrict testing to the file I changed, even if I use the `TESTNAME` flag as specified in the rust test suite documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022 the way to run the test suite for the rust standard library is documented at https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/tests/running.html .

While the documentation mentions the ability to test a single file it appears to malfunction

```
$ ./x.py test library/core/tests/str.rs
Updating only changed submodules
  Submodules updated in 0.01 seconds
Building rustbuild
    Finished dev [unoptimized] target(s) in 0.09s
thread 'main' panicked at 'error: no rules matched library/core/tests/str.rs', src/bootstrap/builder.rs:286:17
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Build completed unsuccessfully in 0:00:00
```

Later on it mentions a different syntax like `./x.py test library/alloc/ --test-args str` which appears to succesfully run the unit tests in `library/alloc/tests/str.rs`

Answer (score 0):

`make check-stage1-std NO_REBUILD=1` or `... check-stage2-std ...` should work, if you've done a full build previously. They just build the test runner directly without doing the rest of the bootstrap.

In any case, the full `std` test runner is built always, since, as you noticed, the imports etc are set up for the full crate. `TESTNAME` is the correct way to restrict which tests are run, but there's no way to restrict tests are built.

Another option is to pull the test/relevant code into an external file, and yet another is to build the test runner by running `rustc` manually on `libstd/lib.rs`: `rustc --test lib.rs`. One could edit the rest of the crate to remove the tests/code you're not interested in.

Comment: There are a lot of suggestions here; I'm going to try to parse them. 1. "make check-stage1-std NO_REBUILD=1 . . . should work, if you've done a full build previously." What is a "full" build? I have run "make all", and this does not work for me, as I noted in my #2.

Comment: 2. "make check-stage2-std NO_REBUILD=1 should work, if you've done a full build previously". This one does seem to "work", but it's testing way more than what I want to test; TESTNAME doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: 3. "there's no way to restrict tests are built." Do standard library developers go through this whole testsuite every time they make a change? Maybe there's another way to get what I want here. Instead of "restricting" which tests are built, can I convince the compiler to set up the imports to use already built files? How to libstd developers do it?

Comment: 4. "Another option is to pull the test/relevant code into an external file". I'm very wary of this as likely to lead to spurious errors. Additionally, I'd prefer to do something "standard" so that any unusual errors I see I can track down without questioning whether I made a copy-paste error when building up my own bowlerized stdlib to just test one part.

Comment: 5. "and yet another is to build the test runner by running rustc manually on libstd/lib.rs: rustc --test lib.rs. One could edit the rest of the crate to remove the tests/code you're not interested in." This works in the raw, but it's not clear which parts of the crate can be removed. Most lines I chose to remove caused the test to fail.

Comment: `make all` (or conventionally just `make`) is what I mean by full build, and so it sounds like there are staging problems. The `...-stage2-...` version is more reliable. `TESTNAME` is used like, for example, `make check-stage2-std NO_REBUILD=1 TESTNAME=pipes` which will run only those tests that have `pipes` in their (module) path. Standard library developers normally use that or iterate out-of-tree and only place it into libstd when it's mostly ready.